# How to use PhoneGap Developer App in Cordova projects

Tags: android, cordova

I am quite new to Cordova, and I recently found the [PhoneGap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com/) which is compatible with PhoneGap and it's [documentation](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/) states that this app can be used with Cordova as well, but I dont know how to use it with Cordova.

Does anyone know how to use this App with Cordova.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Read from here ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758614/which-ui-to-use-for-cordova-android-iphone-app-development/24760861#24760861

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to install PhoneGap `npm install phonegap -g` and then you can call `phonegap serve` on your Cordova-project.