# Is it okay to sideload the PhoneGap Developer App from their github repo?

Tags: android, cordova

The "cordova fork" PhoneGap offers this nice facility called the "PhoneGap Developer App" to preview apps. As it seems to [work with cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733942/how-to-use-phonegap-developer-app-in-cordova-projects), and the build from [source](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer) failed on my first attempt...

***Is it okay*** to use one of the .apk binaries from their repo, [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/tree/master/resources/release/android)? The docs only [mention](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/2-install-mobile-app/) iTunes, Google Play and Windows Phone Store - but I want to / have to sideload the app.

Comment: Of course, it's ok as long as you trust the application author. Loading from Google Play is just for convenience's sake (assuming your device has Google Play in the first place). That being said, if you want to edit the source and then load it on your device, then you'll have to build from the source, but again, that's only if you want to edit the source.

Comment: That was what I was meaning between the lines: 1. Is this repo official (seems so, so it's basically the same people pushing to the stores), 2. I'm not familiar with its source, so are there any defaults set in source that are wrong/harmful?  Answer seems to be: all good - I can side-load it from github.

Comment: "I can't side-load it from github" is not a proper error description. Every time you can't do something, you need to find the actual error message, you need to actually read what it says, try to understand the cause, try to isolate the problem, and if that fails, you need to google for the error itself to see if anyone else has gotten something similar.

Comment: ?? Where are you quoting from? That's not an error message.

Comment: Sorry, this is actually what I was referring to: "the build from source failed on my first attempt...". In other words, "failed on my first attempt" doesn't tell us very much at all.  And when you ask "so are there any defaults set in source that are wrong/harmful?". I'd say yes, probably, there are a thousand and one things that could be wrong.  And then I could enumerate these thousand and one things for you, but the quicker way to check what's wrong  is actually look for an error message either in the console or in logcat. The error message should lead you back to the setting that's wrong.

Comment: Actually even their app on Google Play, that app is getting many 1 star reviews. And the latest positive reviews are from February 2016. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app So anything they introduced in the code only after February 2016 may be what's causing the problems.

Comment: For completeness: My build of the app failed with [this error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724863/how-can-i-fix-the-cannot-find-module-bplist-parser-error-with-phonegap) "Cannot find module 'bplist-parser'" and the offered solution (see link) didn't work on first try. Being not that familiar with npm+cordova, getting the cordova/phonegap stack "right" for a build (for me) can be difficult, so I just gave up there.

Comment: You're actually making progress. Don't give up so easily. "the offered solution (see link) didn't work on first try." Again, what message if any did it give you? "didn't work on first try" could mean a thousand different things. Don't give up just because the solution isn't clear yet. These clues you're getting are important. You need to learn to stop ignoring them. Debugging is a skill. The more you practice debugging problems, the better at it you will become.

Comment: Guru meditation. You're going Zen. ;) (let's put it to rest.)

Comment: Ok. I'm putting it to rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until someone proves me wrong: **yes it's okay** to side-load the app with binary builds from the github repo.

1. Is [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer) an official repo? YES.
2. Is this file/build from a trusted user? Asked myself: Who has committed the .apk file? Example [version 1.6.3](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/commit/a0c6809158df898c1f62fe7d682873042ba8badd) has been committed by github user timkim -> works for Adobe. YES, it's a trusted user.
3. Are there any settings in the devel version which make it unsafe to use? Debug settings or hard-coded endpoints? Without actually looking at the innards - seems no: the app works on the local LAN, with an IP settable by the user. "Calling home" usage stats transmitting can be toggled, and is set to off by default. Concluding: default settings are same as from one of the stores. YES, it's safe.

All good.